# Unable to Bring Image Captured (using camera) In Front of an ImageButton in Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am developing a simple form in Kotlin Android Studio that includes taking a photo using the camera. After taking a photo using the camera, I want the image to be set in the camera button (which is an ImageButton).

Currently, it looks like this,
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uJNP.png)
How do I send the image to front?

I used a bringToFront() method (shown in the code snippet below) but to no avail.

Here are the relevant codes:

```
class FormActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String
    val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1
    var selectedPhotoUri : Uri? = null

    companion object {
        const val REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA = 1001
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_formactivity)

        ...

        val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)

        // to launch the camera
        imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            takePictureUsingCamera()
        }
    }

    private fun takePictureUsingCamera(){
        ImagePicker.with(this).cameraOnly()
            .crop()
            .start(REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA)
    }

    // to access the image captured
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode){
                REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA -> {
                    selectedPhotoUri = data!!.data
                    val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
                    val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)

                    val imageButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.imageButton)
                    // add the image to the image button
                    imageButton.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
                    imageButton.bringToFront()
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XML code:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submitButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinnerRslt"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_camera_capture" />
```

Before: [ImageButton - before clicking/taking a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i8Ra.png)
After: [After the image has been taken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0PCR.png)

Comment: `imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)` – Use the `setImageDrawable()` function instead.

Comment: thank you @MikeM. it worked, HOWEVER, the image does not fit in the ImageButton again. I previously solved this by using `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and `android:scaleType="fitXY"` but its not working now after I changed to setImageDrawable()

Comment: @MikeM. I have edited the question to include the XML codes

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "fit in the ImageButton", or how it's not working now.

Comment: After the user has taken a photo, the photo should be set nicely in the ImageButton (which is square-ish). However, instead of the photo fitting nicely within the ImageButton, the photo taken actually expands the ImageButton @MikeM.

Comment: i have updated the question with screenshots (before and after) of what happens when photo is set in the imagebutton @MikeM.

Comment: If you don't want the `ImageButton` itself to resize, then you _don't_ want the `android:adjustViewBounds` attribute, 'cause that's what that one does. Beyond that, by default the `ImageButton` has a button-style background that's going to add padding around the image drawable. When you were setting your image as the background, that was being replaced, as were its paddings, so your image stretched to fill. You'll have to decide how you want to effect the same behavior; e.g., you could go back to setting the background, and then `setImageDrawable(null)` to get rid of the original image.

Comment: hi, i have removed the `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and also tried by setting it to false but it still did not work. and, by setting to setImageDrawable(null), it will remove the image which is not my target result..

Comment: In rereading this whole thing, I realize now that I'm not sure what you want this to look like, exactly. The first image posted did not have the grey button background, so I assumed that's what you're aiming for. If it's not, and you do actually want to set the new image on the `ImageButton` that still looks like a button, just with a picture instead, then you need to stick with the `setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable)` method, and adjust everything else around that.

Comment: hi, i managed to solve the issue (imageButton getting resized by the image) by assigning a height instead of match-parent in the xml file.

Comment: You mean `wrap_content`? Ah, OK, so you weren't really trying to get rid of the button background, like in the first image. Yeah, when you use any of the `setImage*()` methods, it's setting the `ImageButton`'s content, and `wrap_content` will resize to hold it. The background doesn't work like that, though. Anyhoo, glad you got it figured out. Cheers!

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my questions and help with my issues. appreciate it! Cheers to you as well :-) @MikeM.